# How to make images for Haar training

Tags: opencv3.0, haar-classifier

How I choose positive images for make my model? What I need change on images? thanks! I dont find a tutorial for follow, and the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) dont help me much.
Exemple:
[Brazil coin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auNzQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You want a lot of images of the object, from a number of different facing angles, with different lighting. The more images you have, the stronger your classifier will be.

If you're using the createsamples utility, you want them to have a single flat color as the background (one that doesn't appear in whatever you're actually trying to find - in that coin's case, I'd say white or black). This is so the createsamples can easily remove the background, and substitute whatever background files you decide to use.

If you're not going to use createsamples, then you want a lot of different backgrounds - as different as you can get them.

I tend to use somewhere between 100-200 images, and then use the opencv_createsamples utility with them with somewhere between 20 and 120 sub-images for each image, so a total of somewhere between 2000 and 24000 images. You can use less, but you're more likely to get false reports. (Fair warning, training with more than 10000 images with a larger image (w/h 75+) will take more than a day on most computers)

You're going to likely need a different cascade for top and bottom of the coin, but if there aren't a lot of very similar objects in the image you might be able to get away with just one.